# Creating a Twitter Bootstrap modal in an EmberJS application using bootstrap-for-ember

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, controller, bootstrap-for-ember

Following the guides [here](http://ember-addons.github.io/bootstrap-for-ember/#/show_components/modal), to create a modal dialog programatically.

```
<h1 class="page-header">Welcome!</h1>

{{bs-button title="Create Modal" clicked="createModalProgramatically"}}
```

I created a `modal_controller.js` file and inside it:

```
MyEmberApp.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  manualButtons: [
      Ember.Object.create({title: 'Submit', clicked:"submitManual"}),
      Ember.Object.create({title: 'Cancel', dismiss: 'modal'})
  ],

  actions: {
    submitManual: function() {
      Bootstrap.NM.push('Modal destroyed!', 'success');
      return Bootstrap.ModalManager.close('manualModal');
    },
    createModalProgramatically: function() {
      //@property {string} The name of the modal, required later to close the modal (see submitManual function above)
      //@property {string} The title of the modal.
      //@property {string} The template name to render within the modal body, a View class may also be specified.
      //@property {array} Array of Button meta data
      //@property {object} The controller instance that instantiate the modal.
      Bootstrap.ModalManager.open('manualModal', 'Hello', 'index', this.manualButtons, this);
    }
  }
});
```

I want to extend the ApplicationController (**not the index controller**) because I want to be able to invoke a modal dialog from anywhere in the application programatically.

How can I accomplish this without repeating my modal code on every controller I want to use a modal?

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: This is an excellent opportunity to take advantage of a mixin! Check out the documentation, but effectively all you need to do is take that code and make a mixin for it, and then anywhere you want to use this code, you cna import it by passing it in as a property for the extends. Give this a shot and let me know if you need a JSBIN to demonstrate it.

Answer (score 0):

You make can put the Bootstrap code into a controller like `MyBootstrapController` :

```
MyEmberApp.MyBootstrapController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    manualButtons: [
        Ember.Object.create({title: 'Submit', clicked:"submitManual"}),
        Ember.Object.create({title: 'Cancel', dismiss: 'modal'})
    ],

    actions: {
        submitManual: function() {
            Bootstrap.NM.push('Modal destroyed!', 'success');
            return Bootstrap.ModalManager.close('manualModal');
        },
        createModalProgramatically: function() {
            Bootstrap.ModalManager.open('manualModal', 'Hello', 'index', this.manualButtons, this);
        }
    }
});
```

and then make all your next controllers to inherit from `MyBootstrapController` like this :

```
MyEmberApp.IndexController = MyEmberApp.MyBootstrapController.extend({
     // Some other controller stuff
});
```